# how can I add imaging handling got this script effectively

Tags: php, mysql, forms, upload

hopefully someone can help me here. been up all night browsing and nothing I try seems to work, but im new to php so im slow. I need to upload 6 images, and this works great. but then I realized you can upload not only images but all other file types. Im trying to be able to limit it to just images under 100kb each. heeeeelllllllpppppp!!!! please!

```
function findexts ($filename) { $filename = strtolower('$filename') ; 
$exts = preg_split("[/\\.]", $filename) ;
 $n = count($exts)-1; 
 $exts = $exts[$n];
  return $exts;
   }

$ext = findexts ($_FILES['images']['name']) ; 
$ran = rand ();
$ran2 = $ran.".";

while(list($key,$value) = each($_FILES['images']['name']))
        {
            if(!empty($value))
            {
                $filename = $ran.$value;
                    $filename=str_replace(" "," _ ",$filename);// Add _ inplace of blank space in file name, you can remove this line

                    $add = "media/".$ran."$filename";
                $insert_query = "INSERT INTO ....VALUES ...";
                       //echo $_FILES['images']['type'][$key];
                 // echo "<br>";
                    copy($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key], $add);
                    chmod("$add",0777);

        mysql_query($insert_query);

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the answer to both your questions here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9153419/723855

Add this function to your script (modified from link):

```
function acceptFileUpload($thefile){
    if(isset($_FILES[$thefile])) {
        $errors     = array();
        $maxsize    = 2097152;
        $acceptable = array(
            'application/pdf',
            'image/jpeg',
            'image/jpg',
            'image/gif',
            'image/png'
        );

        if(($_FILES[$thefile]['size'] >= $maxsize) || ($_FILES[$thefile]["size"] == 0)) {
            $errors[] = 'File too large. File must be less than 2 megabytes.';
        }

        if(!in_array($_FILES[$thefile]['type'], $acceptable)) && (!empty($_FILES[$thefile]["type"]))) {
            $errors[] = 'Invalid file type. Only PDF, JPG, GIF and PNG types are accepted.';
        }

        if(count($errors) !== 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            foreach($errors as $error) {
                echo '<script>alert("'.$error.'");</script>';
                return false;
            }

            die(); //Ensure no more processing is done
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your script change your while loop to use this function to check for a valid file:

```
while(list($key,$value) = each($_FILES['images']['name']))
    {
        if(!empty($value))
        {
            if(acceptFileUpload('images'))
            {
            $filename = $ran.$value;
                $filename=str_replace(" "," _ ",$filename);// Add _ inplace of blank space in file name, you can remove this line

                $add = "media/".$ran."$filename";
            $insert_query = "INSERT INTO ....VALUES ...";
                   //echo $_FILES['images']['type'][$key];
             // echo "<br>";
                copy($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key], $add);
                chmod("$add",0777);

    mysql_query($insert_query);
            }
        }

    }
```

I might not have that parameter right that is getting passed to acceptFileUpload().

Comment: thats exactly what I need, but the problem is that I cant figure out how to incorporate that idea into my script

Comment: Try something like that (updated code). You may need to change the name of the $_FILES[] parameter that is getting passed to `acceptFileUpload()`

Answer (score 0):

you can check the file type with

```
$_FILES['image']['type']
```

or if you want to check the extension too

```
$extension = explode('.',(string)$_FILES['image']['name']);
//then check if its "jpg", "gif" or "png"
```

the file size can be checked with

```
$_FILES['image']['size']
```

so your script should be like this for each of your image updates:

```
$extension = explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name']);
$imgextensions = array();
$size      = $_FILES['image']['size'];
if(($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'gif' || $extension == 'png') &&
    $size < 100000 ){
    // upload your file to your filesystem
}else{
    //inform the user
}
```

Comment: thats exactly what I need, but the problem is that I cant figure out how to incorporate that idea into my script

Comment: for: `$_FILES['image']['size']`, i changed image to images because thats the var in my form. but I get: Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdoc...

Comment: you can cast it to String this way: `(string)$_FILES['image']['size']`

Answer (score 0):

Four functions to run on the processing script on each file, if all tests pass then the file meets your conditions and can be safely stored (png / jpg / gif + non-zero + 10Kb limit + is uploaded file)

```
//Example Call: checkFileExtension($_FILES['fieldname']['name']);
function checkFileExtension($filename) {
    $filename = strtolower($filename) ;
    $filenamePartsArray = preg_split("[/\\.]", $filename) ;
    $extension = $filenamePartsArray[count($filenamePartsArray) - 1];
    if (($extension == 'gif') || ($extension == 'jpeg') || ($extension == 'jpg') || ($extension == 'png')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

//Example Call: checkFileMIME($_FILES['fieldname']['type']);
function checkFileMIME($filetype) {
    if (($filetype == 'image/png') || ($filetype == 'image/jpeg') || ($filetype == 'image/gif')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

//Example Call: checkFileSize($_FILES['fieldname']['size'], 10);
function checkFileSize($filesize, $limitKb = 0) {
    if ($filesize == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if ($limitKb != 0) {
        if ($filesize > ($limitKb * 1024)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

//Native Call: is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fieldname']['tmp_name']);
```

Edit: pseudo example use

```
foreach ($_FILES as $fieldname => $file) {
    if ((checkFileExtension($file['name'])) && (checkFileMIME($file['type'])) && (checkFileSize($file['size'], 10)) && (is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name']))) {
        //Move the image with move_uploaded_file
        //Save the file location with DB insert
    }
}
```

Comment: I should of been more specific in my question, but my issue is how would I include something like that in my script? I dont know where to put that