# Error not working on Maximum Upload File Size on PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've been wondering why is it that i got no error when i try to upload file with size more than 2mb?

I already read this [How to limit file upload type file size in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153224/how-to-limit-file-upload-type-file-size-in-php) but still not working. (Note: i'm not working on client side validation here like what it did using javascript).

Here's my code:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Document Title" required autofocus><br>
                        <textarea name="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" rows="10" cols="10"></textarea><br>
                        <input type="file" name="documento" required><br>
                        <button type="upload" name="upload" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open"> </span> Upload</button>
                    </form>
```

Then

```
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    $ddd_t = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
    $ddd_d = htmlspecialchars($_POST['description']);
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
    $date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ;
    $filename = strtolower($_FILES['documento']['name']);
    $target = "../downloads/files/";
    $rand = rand(1,10000);
    $target = $target . $rand . "_" . $filename;
    $maxsize = 2097152;
    $mime_type = array(
        'application/pdf',
        'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
        'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'text/plain',
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
        'application/msword'
        );
    if (empty($ddd_t)) {
        $errorize1 = "Required Title!";
    }
    else{
        if (empty($filename)) {
            $errorize1 = "Required File!";
        }
    }
    if (($_FILES['documento']['size'] > $maxsize) || ($_FILES['documento']['size'] == 0)){
        $errorize = "Max size is 2mb";
    }
    else{
        if (!in_array($_FILES['documento']['type'], $mime_type)){
            $errorize = "Invalid File. Only powerpoint, excel, pdf, word, plain-txt accepted!";
        }
    }
    if (isset($errorize1) || isset($errorize))
    {

    }
    else{
    $_FILES['documento']['name'] = $rand . "_" . $filename;
    $upload_file = ($_FILES['documento']['name']);
    $query = "INSERT INTO files(docu_title, description, link, date) VALUES(:ddd_t, :ddd_d, :document, :date_time)";
    $data = $conn->prepare($query);
    $result = $data->execute(array(':ddd_t' => $ddd_t, ':ddd_d' => $ddd_d, ':document' => $upload_file, ':date_time' => $date_time));
    $move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['documento']['tmp_name'], $target);
    if ($result && $move) {
        $upload_img = header("location:?success=true&file=".$_FILES['documento']['name']);
    }
    else{
        echo "error!";
    }
    }
}
```

And

```
<?php
            if (isset($errorize)) {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>'. $errorize .'</div>';
            }
            if (isset($errorize1)) {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>'. $errorize1 .'</div>';
            }
            ?>
```

Only the invalid mime type here is working.. I don't know what's wrong with the file size error when i try to upload more than 2mb.

Comment: check out php ini and see what is the upload_max_filesize  and its 2MB by default. You need to change that to allow upload more than 2 MB

Comment: I can see 2M in the upload_max_filesize .. no, i won't change that.. i just need to warn user if he/she uploaded more than 2mb. that is why i made my own custom error message $errorize ..

Comment: Sidenote: This `$upload_img = header("location:?success=true&file=".$_FILES['document']['name']);` should probably be `$upload_img = header("location:?success=true&file=".$_FILES['documento']['name']);` yet it won't fix your problem, just pointing something out.

Comment: yes, sorry.. i already change that :) but nothing works

Comment: You also could change the limit size using `.htaccess` if you can't modify your `php.ini` file. That's usually the fix. @user3258603

Comment: sorry if my question above is ambiguous. i don't need to change the file limit size in the php.ini. i am sticking to 2mb limit.. the only thing i need here is, if somebody uploaded a file more than 2mb, my error message should warn them that the file they are uploading is beyond the size limit.. that is why i made `if (isset($errorize)) {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>'. $errorize .'</div>';
            }` for them to know..

Comment: So, your error message is "not" appearing, is that it? @user3258603

Comment: Instead of `if (isset($errorize))` and `if (isset($errorize1))` can you try `if ($errorize)` and `if ($errorize1)`

Comment: Yes @Fred-ii- .. the error message is not appearing ..

Comment: Did you try my suggestion just above your comment?

Comment: yes, i also tried that.. but i got an error .. **Undefined variable: errorize**

Comment: @user3258603 look and try my edited answer down .

Comment: It has nothing to do with your answer. Read all of the comments in this thread. @echo_Me - Either delete your answer, or change it to fix the actual problem.

Comment: I tested your code and it worked fine for me. It might be the way you placed your code. I will post an answer below with how I placed mine, then try it again. @user3258603

Comment: It's posted below. @user3258603

Answer (score 0):

in php.ini  check this

```
upload_max_filesize
max_input_time
memory_limit
max_execution_time
post_max_size

upload_max_filesize = 2M` please increase the limit 

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2M  do it as you want
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code placement may be the issue here.

Upon testing the following, the error messages did appear correctly if a document was either too large or was not the right type.

The following is to be inside ONE file.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    $ddd_t = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
    $ddd_d = htmlspecialchars($_POST['description']);
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
    $date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ;
    $filename = strtolower($_FILES['documento']['name']);
    $target = "../downloads/files/";
    $rand = rand(1,10000);
    $target = $target . $rand . "_" . $filename;
    $maxsize = 2097152;

    $mime_type = array(
        'application/pdf',
        'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
        'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'text/plain',
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
        'application/msword'
        );
    if (empty($ddd_t)) {
        $errorize1 = "Required Title!";
    }
    else{
        if (empty($filename)) {
            $errorize1 = "Required File!";
        }
    }
    if (($_FILES['documento']['size'] > $maxsize) || ($_FILES['documento']['size'] == 0)){
        $errorize = "Max size is 2mb";
    }
    else{
        if (!in_array($_FILES['documento']['type'], $mime_type)){
            $errorize = "Invalid File. Only powerpoint, excel, pdf, word, plain-txt accepted!";
        }
    }
    if (isset($errorize1) || isset($errorize))
    {

    }
    else{
    $_FILES['documento']['name'] = $rand . "_" . $filename;
    $upload_file = ($_FILES['documento']['name']);
    $query = "INSERT INTO files(docu_title, description, link, date) VALUES(:ddd_t, :ddd_d, :document, :date_time)";
    $data = $conn->prepare($query);
    $result = $data->execute(array(':ddd_t' => $ddd_t, ':ddd_d' => $ddd_d, ':document' => $upload_file, ':date_time' => $date_time));
    $move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['documento']['tmp_name'], $target);
    if ($result && $move) {
         $upload_img = header("location:?success=true&file=".$_FILES['documento']['name']);
    }
    else{
        echo "error!";
    }
    }
}

?>

<?php
if (isset($errorize)) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>'. $errorize .'</div>';
}
if (isset($errorize1)) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>'. $errorize1 .'</div>';
}
?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Document Title" required autofocus><br>
<textarea name="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" rows="10" cols="10"></textarea><br>
<input type="file" name="documento" required><br>
<button type="upload" name="upload" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open"> </span> Upload</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Actually, in that way i wrote the code .. but still it doesn't work.. i'll try to paste my whole code for this page in pastebin..

Comment: That's strange. Are you using any other code in conjunction with it? @user3258603

Comment: And what are the exact steps that you took? I.e.: 1) Choose a file larger than accepted. 2) Choose a different filetype. @user3258603 that is what I did, and worked for both instances.

Comment: Yes Sir.. that's exactly i am doing here.. i really don't know whats wrong with my code.. BTW, here is the entire code http://pastebin.com/efmsG0n1

Comment: In your pastebin you have `if (isset($errorize1))` and then show `</button>'. $errorize .'</div>';` notice the `1` in `$errorize1` but not in `$errorize` ? Then you have `if (isset($errorize1)) {` using `</button>'. $errorize1 .'</div>';` - both are using `$errorize1` so `if (isset($errorize1)) {` being the first one, should be `if (isset($errorize)) {` --- Plus, it might also be a mix of something else, being the CSS styles associated with it. @user3258603

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.. but still when i edited `if (isset($errorize)) </button>'. $errorize .'</div>';` then `if (isset($errorize1)) </button>'. $errorize1 .'</div>';` nothing happened.. This is also my problem with my other school project, when i try to upload file i cannot echo out the error message if it goes beyond the upload limit.

Comment: I'm sure it has something to do with CSS and not PHP. Are you running this from a PC or mobile/iPad? @user3258603 -

Comment: Because like I wrote, my tests were conclusive and worked. I don't have the CSS/JS that you have loaded, so I'm convinced that's the problem. Both error messages appeared respectively. @user3258603