# How to add Image Size validation in php 5.6

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, php-5.6

I want to add limitation in my uploading image file.I want to validate size to 500kb.Here is my code.

```
    if(empty($_FILES["uthu"]["name"]))
        $errors[] = "Thumb was empty";
    if($_FILES["uthu"]["error"] != 0)
        $errors[] = "error uploading Thumbnail";
        $ext = strtolower(substr($_FILES["uthu"]["name"], -4));
    if($ext != ".jpg")
        $errors[] = "upload .jpg for Thumb";

        $fnm1 = time().rand(1111,9999)."_".$_FILES["uthu"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uthu"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/".$fnm1);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit file upload type file size in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153224/how-to-limit-file-upload-type-file-size-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the file size by below code

```
// You should also check filesize here. 
if ($_FILES['uthu']['size'] > 500000) {
    $errors[] = "Exceeded filesize limit";
}
```