# When User select the image in greater then 2 mb the php get the size zero

Tags: php, mysql, fileapi

When User Select the image of less then 2 mb its show the size and work correctly .Its size greater then 2 mb its not get the size and show error message.

```
if($_FILES['image']){
    $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    if($file_size > (2222222)) {
        echo "Please Select File less then 2 mb";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please specif more what need?

If you question is why only 2 MB, you can check php.ini

Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.

`upload_max_filesize`

Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize

`post_max_size`

If you want limit your img size on php go [How to limit file upload type file size in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153224/how-to-limit-file-upload-type-file-size-in-php)

Comment: my question is when image size is 2MB its not get the size e.g the image size is 100KB its show  the size 100KB but its image size is greater then 2 MB its show the size is zero.

Comment: Check php.ini as say in my anwers

Comment: If you have upload_max_filesize 2MB you can change

Comment: Solved you problem?

Comment: Yes Problem Solve